# How to use interface signal to iterate through numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, pygears

I have troubles with iterating through numpy matrix using interface signal.
I tried to manually cast "addr" but it does not work.
This is my code:

```
@gear
    async def ram_model_data_drv(addr: Uint[8],*,
                                 data_type = b'dtype',
                                 num_of_commands = 1) -> Queue['data_type']:
        matrix = np.random.randint(10, size = (num_of_commands, 10))
        async with addr:
            for data, last in quiter(matrix[addr]):
                yield (data, last)
```

And this is error message which I am receiving.

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices, in the module "/ram_model_drv"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that you are using an interface object (`addr`) to slice a matrix. Interface objects in PyGears are passed via positional arguments (only `addr` in your case) of the functions and are used for communication between the modules. On the other hand, the keyword-only arguments (`data_type` and `num_of_commands` in your case) can carry any kind of object, but are usually used as compile time parameters.

Anyways, although you correctly used the `async with` statement to obtain data from the `addr` interface, you should have placed the obtained data into a new variable like this: `async with addr as a`, which should read as: "Wait for the data to become available on the `addr` interface, read them and store them into variable called `a`".

Side note, you used `b'dtype'` as a value for data_type parameter, but `dtype` is neither a parameter name nor a name of a type template, so it is redundant here. My guess is that you wanted for the user of the module to supply the `data_type` parameter as an output data type, so you should have left it without a default value.

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Queue
import numpy as np
from pygears.util.utils import quiter


@gear
async def ram_model_data_drv(addr: Uint[8],
                             *,
                             data_type,
                             num_of_commands=1) -> Queue['data_type']:
    matrix = np.random.randint(10, size=(num_of_commands, 10))
    async with addr as a:
        for data, last in quiter(matrix[a]):
            yield (data, last)
```